# how to check if NSMutableArray element is NSNull or AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsnull

I have a `PersonsArray: NSMutableArray = [NSNull, NSNull, NSNUll, NSNull, NSNull, NSNUll, NSNull]`. I needed seven slots that I then can fill with an Entity CoreData entry as AnyObject.

I need to do a for in loop on this NSMutableArray...

If the index slot is NSNull I want to pass to next index slot, if index slot is filled with my Object I want to execute code on this Object.

---

```
example PersonsArray: NSMutableArray = [
    NSNull,
    NSNull,
    NSNull,
    "<iswift.Person: 0x7f93d95d6ce0> (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://8DD0B78C-C624-4808-9231-1CB419EF8B50/Person/p2> ; data: {\n    image = nil;\n    name = dustin;\n})",
    NSNull,
    NSNull,
    NSNull
]
```

Attempting

```
for index in 0..<PersonsArray.count {
        if PersonsArray[index] != NSNull {println(index)}
}
```

suggests a bunch of changes that don't work either, like

```
if PersonsArray[index] as! NSNull != NSNull.self {println(index)}
```

or

```
if PersonsArray[index] as! NSNull != NSNull() {println(index)}
```

---

NOTE: using NSNull is just a placeholder in NSMutableArray so that its count is ALWAYS 7 and I can replace any of the (7)slots with an Object. Should I be using something other than NSNull as my placeholder?

Comment: `NSNull` is probably defined as always returning `false` from any `==` or `!=` comparison.  That's how null does in most places...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSNull()` is a singleton object, therefore you can simply test if
the array element is an instance of `NSNull`:

```
if personsArray[index] is NSNull { ... }
```

or use the "identical to" operator:

```
if personsArray[index] === NSNull() { ... }
```

Alternatively, you could use an array of optionals:

```
let personsArray = [Person?](count: 7, repeatedValue: nil)
// or more verbosely:
let personsArray : [Person?] = [ nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil ]
```

using `nil` for the empty slots.

Comment: Wouldn't `is NSNull` work even if it weren't a singleton object?  Doesn't it follow that because it's a singleton object that `===` would probably work (compare references?).

Comment: Since it's a singleton you can test if the array element `== [NSNull null]` (in Objective-C notation).

Comment: @HotLicks Objective-C's `== [NSNull null]` is a reference comparison.  `==` in Swift would be more like doing `isEqual:[NSNull null]]` in Objective-C, but `===` is Swift's reference comparison.

Comment: @nhgrif: I was just about to add the `===` version.

Comment: turns out I was populating original PersonsArray = [[NSNull.self, NSNull.self, NSNull.self, NSNull.self, NSNull.self, NSNull.self,NSNull.self] and it isn't equal to PersonsArray = [NSNull(),NSNull(),NSNull(),NSNull(),NSNull(),NSNull(),NSNull()]

Comment: @Dustin: `NSNull.self` is the *class* (or *type*) object,that is probably not what you want. `NSNull()` is the "null object".

Comment: @Martin R trying PersonsArray = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] produces error "Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'"... so just to be certain...Using NSNull() as my placeholder is okay or not... the `if personsArray[index] === NSNull() { ... }` works with NSNull() as placeholder

Comment: @Dustin: You cannot use NSMutableArray to store nils. Try the definition at the end of my answer.

Comment: === NSNull() works, is there a good reason to use nil instead?

Comment: @Dustin You must use `NSNull()` if you're using an `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray()`.  You can use `nil` if you have a Swift array of an optional type.

Comment: @Dustin: `nil` is the Swift way of expressing "no value". The advantage would be that you have a typed array `[Person?]`, so that the *compiler* can already check that only `Person` objects (or nil) is stored. In an `NSMutableArray` you can store almost anything.

Comment: @MartinR would that solve my issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956065/how-to-deal-with-nsmutablearray-containing-coredata-entry-after-entry-is-deleted/29957579#29957579

Comment: @Dustin: No, I don't think so. *This* question is about how to store "nothing" in an array. *That* question is about Core Data.