# how to deal with NSMutableArray containing CoreData Entry after Entry is deleted from CoreData, showing as "<fault>"

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmutablearray, fault

PersonsArray: NSMutableArray =

```
(
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<MyProject.Person: 0x7ffc5257d850> (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://8DD0B78C-C624-4808-9231-1CB419EF8B50/Person/p1> ; data: {\n    image = nil;\n    name = dustin;\n})",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>")
```

if the user deletes CoreData Entry (entity: Person; name = dustin)

PersonsArray: NSMutableArray =

```
(
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<MyProject.Person: 0x7ffc5257d850> (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://8DD0B78C-C624-4808-9231-1CB419EF8B50/Person/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>")
```

How can I check if a index slot of `PersonsArray` contains this `"<fault>"` so that I can return it to `"<null>"`?

---

My code that deletes entry in tableView (second VC)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            //Could I do something like give VC2 the PersonsArray and here...
            //ADD Something like
            for ObjectIndex in 0..<PersonsArray.count {
                 if PersonsArray[ObjectIndex] === results[indexPath.row] { 
                     PersonsArray[ObjectIndex] = NSNull()
                 }
            }
            // then continue with the delete?

            context.deleteObject(results[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
            context.save(nil)
            self.viewDidLoad()
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no easy way.  The right answer is ... don't store `NSManagedObject` instances in an array.  Use NSFetchedResultsController, etc. when you are in that situation or refetch the objects to determine what is left.

Another option is to manually maintain the array by listening for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notifications and removing objects from the array when they are deleted from the context.

Using a `NSFetchedResultsController` is generally easier.

### Update 1

In your main view controller you can hold a reference to the `-objectID` instead of the object.  Then when you attempt to realize the object you will get back a `nil` if it is gone.  Not pretty but that can work.

Instead, however, your main view controller should listen for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and in that notification is a `-userInfo` and inside of that property are three `NSSet` instances.  One containing all objects that were updated, one for all that were inserted and for all that were deleted.  You can then test to see if anything that was deleted was in your array and remove them from your array.

Comment: so i have my second ViewController which contains a TableView that fetches all possible `Person` Entity and refetches when a new entity is saved... In my MainViewController I have an array of selected `Person` entities that user has chosen from TableView in particular ordered index slots... But if User deletes an Entry from TableView/CoreData that is currently in selected Array..."<fault>"...SO YOU ARE SAYING... I can listen for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notifications. Does this notification occur when an entry is deleted?? And I will research what a `NSFetchedResultsController` is. ty

Comment: Is it possible to...Everytime before deletion of an entry is completed, I check PersonsArray to see if it contains an entry === entry being deleted? and If so change that object to the NSNull() placeholder, then complete deletion?

Comment: Which Im actually confused how it worked...because I still haven't pass the  array back to my mainVC...and yet it is updated.