# How to Compare AnyObject Is <Null> or not?

Tags: ios, swift, anyobject

I am writing below function to return value based on data objet that I passed to this method.

If we get data null I am trying to return "-" otherwise If I get any valid response I am returning value..

```
private func checkDataForValue(data: Optional<AnyObject>) -> String {
    if let value = data {
        let value1: AnyObject = //have to check <Null>
        if value === value1 {
            return "-"
        }
        return "\(value)"
    } else {
        return "-"
    }
}
```

My question How to compare null value here ..

Comment: The `if let` is already check to see if `data` is `nil` or not. `value` can't be `nil`.

Comment: `AnyObject` can't be null. Only optionals can be null. Except for perhaps `NSNull`, I don't know much about how that bridges into swift from ObjC

Comment: Thanks rmaddy ..but here value coming as <Null> and it's coming into the loop not going out..!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954806/how-to-check-if-nsmutablearray-element-is-nsnull-or-anyobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are looking to compare `value` with `NSNull`.

You can update your code as follows:

```
private func checkDataForValue(data: Any?) -> String {
    if let value = data {
        if value is NSNull != nil {
            return "-"
        } else if (value as? String)?.lowercased() == "<null>" {
            return "-"
        } else {
            return "\(value)"
        }
    } else {
        return "-"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `value is NSNull` instead of `value as? NSNull != nil` ?

Comment: @OOPer Because sometimes you forget the obvious. :) That would be simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, Here I am trying to get value and "value as? NSNull == nil ? "\(value)" : "-" " Is giving me value with optional character(optional(8))..Any ideas how to remove that optional char ..

Comment: I want value if it's not nill and if it's nill "-" but above logic is not giving "-" when it's nill.

Comment: If `data` is `nil` then you get `-` from the `else`. If `data` is not `nil` then `value is compared against `NSNull`. If `value` is an instance of `NSNull`, you get `-`, otherwise you get a string representation of `value`. If you are still getting `<Null>` then `data` isn't `nil` nor is it an instance of `NSNull`. It must be a `String` with the value `<Null>`. After the `if let`, before the `return`, add `print(type(of: value))`. Update your question with the result of that line.

Comment: print(type(of: value)) it will have Int and String objets.. If data is nill it's not going into else loop it's still going into if loop..!

Comment: You need to actually add that line and run your code. Tell is the output of that `print` when you are getting `<Null>` as a result.

Comment: I added that line and the value is nil but it's going into if loop,  when I print that I am getting Optional<Int> or Optional<String>.

Comment: Sounds like your data contains the literal string "<Null>"  Again, telling us how you're getting the original data *might* help us figure out what's going on.  But we still don't know exactly what @rmaddy's fragment prints WHEN you get the "<Null>" result.

Comment: @tarun Try my update. This deals with the literal string `"<Null>"`. And there's no loop here. Instead of saying the "if loop", say the "if block" vs "else block".

Comment: @rmaddy Yes It did .. Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of the power of switch cases and go with:

```
private func checkDataForValue(data: Any?) -> String {
    switch data {
    case .none, .some(is NSNull):       return "-"
    case .some(let value as String):    return value == "<null>" ? "-" : value
    case .some(let value):              return "\(value)"
    }
}
```

Comment: As @rmaddy suggests, try adding `print(type(of: data))` to see what it is that you're really getting then.  It may just be a string containing "<null>" and not an `NSNull` issue at all.  It also might help to have some context around your question and the usage of `checkDataForValue`

Comment: If I add print(type(of: data)) in above code I am getting <null> and It's not a NSNull it is String though..

Comment: Updated the chunk above to cover the string literal "<null>" case.